# Will having 2FA protect me on a potentially insecure network?

Tags: multi-factor

Whenever I browse to a Google site on my Library's network, I get this screen:

[image]

Presumably this is so they can "protect" children (anyone with a library card who is under 13) from unsafe videos as [safety mode can be overridden if you log in to your account](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/174084?hl=en). But, I don't know that's the *only* reason they're doing it and the network may (in theory) be compromised. If I login to my Google account, the library could preform a MITM attack, even though the page is SSL. They would be able to see my password, but would they still be able to login to my account if I had 2FA?

Comment: you have a misunderstanding of this message - it's saying that the encrypted tunnel between you and Google has potential problems - it is not a "content warning" message

Comment: in fact, one of the reasons why you would see this message is if there was a MITM attack going on

Comment: @schroeder I Think the OP understands that the library has a SSL MITM scanning solution like Bluecoat Proxy SG or something similiar, and what he ask now is if the library IT personell do have access to his account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I generally agree with @schroeder, one point of difference is that, without 2FA, once your password is captured in this MITM scenario the attacker has unrestricted access to your account.  However, with 2FA, even if they MITM your password and your one-time-password, this access will only allow them to see your traffic while they are actively intercepting your session (as it is a one-time/time-based token, the 2FA code can't be used to log in again from another machine the attacker controls).  So, even in totally insecure environments, it's always better to use 2FA than not.  In other words, the library could, potentially, see your ongoing session while you're there, but they could not, in the future, log into your account when you're not there.

Comment: I meant to include the concept that the MITM doesn't have unrestricted access and I made an edit to my answer.

Comment: While generally your answer is true and should be practiced always, if the attacker gets access to the user password and the also the 2FA code, then he can just turn off 2FA for future to gain unlimited access as turning it off only require password.

Comment: Maybe, but only until the first time you log in and notice that 2FA isn't asking for the password :-) Also, some providers/services ask for extra confirmation/info (e.g., security questions, a second code, etc.) when one tries to turn off 2FA on an account, effectively mitigating this attack.

Answer (score 2):

2FA would not protect you when in a MITM situation. Imagine this scenario: the Google login page is fake, and everything you enter is captured by the MITM. You supply your credentials, then the fake site passes that on to Google. Google challenges the MITM for the 2FA code, but passes that request on to you. You supply the passcode, and now the MITM passes that on. The MITM is now properly authenticated and passed 2FA. They now have control over your account: they could stop allowing you to access the session and take over, or watch your session in secret.

2FA is primarily meant to protect you from malicious actors trying to bruteforce your account or using a captured password.

Comment: But they wouldn't be able to login with the stolen login information as the code changes every 30(?) seconds, right? Even if they did capture that it wouldn't help.

Comment: Who's "they"? The mitm or the brute forcer?

Comment: MITM­­­­­­­­­­­

Comment: The MITM in my scenario is already logged in because you gave them your 2FA. If they made no changes to your account, they would not be able to log in again, but they could also lock you out and change the settings on the account.

Answer (score 0):

2FA is meant to help only in the initial login. You depend on end to end encryption to safeguard the transmissions. Conceivably you could force the user to reinput whatever tokens are available to reinstate the perceived trust between you and the endpoint, but as people goes, typing in the password multiple times is not a great convenience that anyone would want to go through. I really recommend you look at the evolution of password signons from ncsa mosaic days till today, where internet explorer has been put out to pasture.